# How to refresh automaticaly a list of posts with vuex?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuex, crud

i'm working on a project who turn on an Laravel and Vuejs like an SPA. On the admin page, where a manage the posts, i render a list of the posts in database with vuex and axios request. And i've got a button to delete a post.

But when i delete a post the list is not refresh and i need to refresh the page manualy. Why the vuex is not refresh the state ?

**backend/post/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="post-index">
    <h1>All Posts</h1>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'posts.create' }" class="nav-link" active-class="active">
      <p class="new-post-btn">
        Créer Un nouveau Guide
      </p>
    </router-link>

    <table class="table post-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
            #
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Title
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Is Publish
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Create At
          </th>
          <th scope="col">
            Actions
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="guide in guides.post" v-bind:key="getPosts">
          <th scope="row">
            {{ guide.id }}
          </th>
          <th>{{ guide.title }}</th>
          <th>{{ guide.is_publish }}</th>
          <th>{{ guide.created_at }}</th>
          <th>
            <i class="fas fa-times" />
            <button class="edit-button">
              <router-link :to="{ name: 'posts.create' }">
                <fa icon="edit" fixed-width />
              </router-link>
            </button>
            <button class="delete-button" @click="deletePost(guide.id)">
              <fa icon="times" fixed-width />
            </button>
            <button class="publish-button">
              <fa icon="paper-plane" fixed-width />
            </button>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      guides: null
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      posts: 'post/post'
    })
  },

  beforeCreate () {
    this.$store.dispatch('post/fetchPosts')
  },

  created () {
    this.getPosts()
  },

  methods: {
    getPosts () {
      this.guides = this.$store.state.post
    },
    deletePost (postId) {
      this.$store.commit('DELETE_POST', postId)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**store/module/post.js**

```
    import axios from 'axios'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

// State
export const state = {
  post: null
}

// Getters
export const getters = {
  post: state => state.post
}

export const mutations = {
  [types.SAVE_POST] (state, { post }) {
    axios.post('/api/posts/store', {
      post
    })
    state.post = post
  },

  [types.DELETE_POST] (state, id) {
    var index = state.post.findIndex(p => p.id === id)
    state.post.splice(index, 1)
  },

  [types.FETCH_POST_SUCCESS] (state, { post }) {
    state.post = post
  },

  [types.FETCH_POST_FAILURE] (state) {
    state.post = null
  }
}

export const actions = {

  savePost ({ commit, dispatch }, payload) {
    commit(types.SAVE_POST, payload)
  },

  async fetchPosts ({ commit }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/posts/index')
      console.log(data)
      commit(types.FETCH_POST_SUCCESS, { post: data })
    } catch (e) {
      commit(types.FETCH_POST_FAILURE)
    }
  },

  deletePost ({ commit }, post) {
    axios.delete('/api/posts/delete/' + post.id)
      .then(function () {
        commit(types.DELETE_POST, post)
      })
  }
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies where you have defined `fetchPosts` and handle `DELETE_POST`.

To fix it, make sure that committing `DELETE_POST` reloads or deletes that particular element from `this.$store.state.post`.

Then the computed `mapGetters` should automatically refresh your posts.

Comment: Sorry i duplicate the first code, i edit to change the second code section to show my store for posts

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the store is correct, but it was a bad calling of the store with the hooks of vuejs in my component.